# Postgres: Password authentication failed for user "user". Role "user" does not exists

Tags: django, postgresql, cookiecutter-django

I'm using Django created with the template cookie-cutter. 
When I try to run the project with docker locally it gives me the following error.

> FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "user"
>   DETAIL:  Role "user" does not exist.

But the role "user" exists. Using the command `postgres=# \du` gives me the role "user"

I have a `.env` file with the recommended configuration by cookie cutter.
`POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password`

`POSTGRES_USER=user`

I tried giving the user a password and granting all privileges of the database to the user but doesn't work.

Comment: What does the PostgreSQL log say if `log_connections = on`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually connection problems are due to:

`postgresql.conf` not having the `listen_addresses` set correctly or the `pg_hba.conf` not having correct values.

It often helps to increase postgresql logging in `postgresql.conf` to watch what happens when connecting

`log_min_duration_statement = 0  ## logs all statements`

You could also try at cmd prompt:
`pg_isready -d dbname -U user`